# Duplicate information in useState variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, solidity

So I'm having the problem of having duplicate information into an array useState variable. This is my code:

```
const [tokens, setTokens] = useState([]);

const getTokens = async () => {
    const nftContract = await getContract(true);
    const tokensIds = await nftContract.getTokenIds();
    setTokens([]);

    for (var i = 0; i < tokensIds.length; i++) {
      const id = tokensIds[i].toNumber();
      if (id != 0) {
        const atts = await nftContract.getTokenAttrs(tokensIds[i]);
        const data = { tokenId: id, product: atts[2], quantity: atts[3], unit: atts[4], state: atts[5] };

        setTokens(
          state => [...state, data]
        )
      }
    } 
    setLoading(false);
  };

useEffect(() => {

    const nftContract = new Contract(NFT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi, props.provider);
    var currentAccount;
    props.provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", [])
      .then(function (result) {
        currentAccount = utils.getAddress(result[0]);
      });

    getTokens()
      .then(
        // listen to all events triggered for all minted tokens from this account
        nftContract.on(nftContract.filters.Transaction(currentAccount, null, 0), (_from, _tokenId, _state) => {
          console.log("Listener triggered FARMER - 1");
          getTokens();
        })
      )
    );

    // we remove all the events to avoid they fire multiple timess
    return () => {
      props.provider.removeAllListeners()
    }

}, []);
```

As you can see, in the **useEffect**, there is a listener that when an event is triggered, will run the **getTokens()** function. The problem comes when there are two events that triggers this function, making the tokens useState variable have **duplicate values**. I've tried to initialize the variable at the beginning of the function with setTokens([]) but it doesn't work... Any solution that you can propose me?

Answer (score 0):

Initialise state as a [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Each record in the map should be keyed by token id. That way you guarantee no duplicate entries.

```
const [tokens, setTokens] = useState(new Map());


const getTokens = async () => {
    const nftContract = await getContract(true);
    const tokensIds = await nftContract.getTokenIds();
    setTokens([]);

    for (var i = 0; i < tokensIds.length; i++) {
      const id = tokensIds[i].toNumber();
      if (id != 0) {
        const atts = await nftContract.getTokenAttrs(tokensIds[i]);
        const data = { tokenId: id, product: atts[2], quantity: atts[3], unit: atts[4], state: atts[5] };
        tokens.set(id, data);
        setTokens(tokens);
      }
    } 
    setLoading(false);
  };

useEffect(async() => {

    const nftContract = new Contract(NFT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi, props.provider);
    var currentAccount;
    props.provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", [])
      .then(function (result) {
        currentAccount = utils.getAddress(result[0]);
      });

    await getTokens();
     
    // listen to all events triggered for all minted tokens from this account
    nftContract.on(nftContract.filters.Transaction(currentAccount, null, 0), async (_from, _tokenId, _state) => {
          console.log("Listener triggered FARMER - 1");
          await getTokens();
        })
      )
    );

    // we remove all the events to avoid they fire multiple timess
    return () => {
      props.provider.removeAllListeners()
    }

}, []);
```

You can get the entry values with

```
tokens.values();
```